# Запрос на сервер с API

Tags: api, запрос, javascript

Есть API с расписанием. Я делаю кросс-доменный запрос, и он вроде как работает, так как в хроме появляется в ресурсах (ссылка на скрин http://i67.fastpic.ru/big/2014/0927/5c/28f2ecf7369ba09e5eaf0cbe8d27f35c.png ), но информацию, которую мне надо, не выводит. А если данные взять и запихнуть в файл, например, get.json, и поместить на свой сервер - все работает. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем ошибка?

```
<html>
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
   <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("button").click(function(){
        var url = "http://api.rozklad.org.ua/v1/groups/561/lessons/?week=1&day=1";
        $.ajax({
            url : url,
            type : "GET",
            dataType : "jsonp",
            success : function(msg){
                document.getElementById('paste').innerHTML = msg[0].day_name
            }
        });
      });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="paste"> </div>
   <button>Send</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Почитайте про CORS.

Comment: С кроссдоменностю вроде как все нормально, можешь посмотреть  http://sergtest.meximas.com/